# What happens when there is multiple expressions in the condition part of a for loop seperated by commas?

Tags: c, loops, syntax, comma-operator

I have an infinite loop here, but why?

```
int end = 5;
for(int i = 0; i < end, printf("at condition i=%d\n",i); ++i) 
{
    printf("inside i=%d\n",i);
}
```

Comment: Related to [What does the comma operator , do in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do-in-c) ... maybe a dup?  Usually it is used in the [initialization section of the for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18444099/1708801).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The left operand of the comma operator is evaluated as a void expression, the evaluated result of a comma operator is the result of the right operand. So the "if" part of your `for` loop looks at the result of the `printf`, which is higher than zero, meaning it will never end.

You can fix it by swapping them:

```
int end = 5;
for(int i = 0; printf("at condition i=%d\n",i), i < end; ++i) 
{
    printf("inside i=%d\n",i);
}
```

But better is to not do this at all. It is not very readable.

Comment: -1 This has nothing to do with associativity and it has everything to do with how the comma operator works, C11 6.5.17 "`The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void expression; there is a sequence point between its evaluation and that of the right operand. Then the right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value`"

Comment: @Lundin thanks, I messed the terms a little, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The comma operator expression `i < end, printf("at condition i=%d\n",i)` is used as condition. Its value is its right operand, which is the return value of `printf`.

The return value of `printf` is the number of characters it outputs, that's never zero in this case, so it's an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

If compiled with `-Wall`,

```
warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect
```

So `i < end` has no effect. `printf()` return no.of characters it printed. 
 
Based on return value(Non zero value here), infinite loop occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn about [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator). The result of comma expression is the result of right operand. In controlling expression `i < end, printf("at condition i=%d\n",i)`, `i < end` is evaluated and its result is discarded.
So, the loop is controlled by the value of the expression `printf("at condition i=%d\n",i)` which returns number of characters that it prints and hence it evaluated always as `true` here and results in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Because

1) `i < end, printf("at condition i=%d\n",i)` returns the same value as `printf("at condition i=%d\n",i)`.

2) `printf()` returns number of printed characters (it is not zero in this case)

So condition in your loop is always true.

Answer (score 0):

In the expression `i < end, printf("at condition i=%d\n")`, the comma operator causes the two expressions to be evaluated in sequence, but the result of the first expression is discarded, and only the result of `printf` is used to control the loop. Since `printf` will always return non-zero for that format string, the loop never terminates.

Use `&&` instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < end && printf("at condition i=%d\n"); i++)
```